# Telerik RadForm Edges missing

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am the Developer of a ClickOnce C# Winforms App that uses Telerik Controls (Version 2016.2.608.20).

As you can see, the edges seem to be cut off. According to the customer, the problem occurs on more than one PC, but i am not able to reproduce that problem on any of my machines. Can anyone think of a pssoible reason why this keeps happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue logged on the [Telerik UI for WinForms feedback portal](http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/154/Feedback/Details/194568). As the portal information states, it will be included in the next R3 2016 release, which is due in 2-3 weeks.

If it is so urgent, you can use the workaround provided on the issue page.